# Can I have a folder that belongs to more than 1 SVN repository?

Tags: svn

Essentially, I'm looking at a folder that can act as both a repository, and also syncable to another repository. I understand I can overcome this by checking out into 2 folders. But I'm facing space constraint, so can I have a folder structure with more than 1 SVN config?

Thanks!

Use Case Request: Have 2 computers syncing to a folder. However both computers are not connected to network, and are connectable by a thumb drive. How can I sync the folders from the 2 computers?

My idea is to have a repository in the thumb drive, and sync to it. However, the computers can ALSO can connectable to the Internet, in this case, we do not need the thumb drive, and I do not want it to be a dependency, so making 1 of those 2 computers a repository is a method. So in essence, on of the computers, 1 folder is possibly both syncing to another repository, and a repo itself. Is this clear?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to do, or why you would do it. Can you provide a use case?

Comment: Added a use case, check it out! :)

Comment: For this reason distributed VCS exists

Comment: Haha, I agree, and assuming it is GIT, the colleagues I'm working with has no prior experience with any revision control at all. So SVN seems like the one with the smallest learning curve. Is there any other distributed VCS you would recommend that is easy to learn?

Comment: you can use the subversion relocate command to switch your working copy between the 2 repositories

Comment: For smaller learning curve I would recommend bazaar. I think it is easier to pick up for newbie to distributed version control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very clear by your explanation, either you have a folder that can be synch to 2 different repository or you want your folder also acting as repository for other while actually a working copy of svn?

Anyway, for the first case you might be able to use `svn switch --relocate` command to change which repository your working copy connecting to. This only work if your repository is actually the same but on different location. See [the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html) for details.

The other possibility that you might want to look at is distributed version control system like git or mercurial. With these tools you can have multiple independent repository which can pull/push changes from each other.

Comment: +1 for the Git recommendation. It is really much better designed to handle this kind of scenario.